# Netplan file order

Tags: networking, server, netplan

I need help understanding the order in which the netplan config files are applied and, if possible, how to set a fallback config.

**Scenario:**

- Let's say I have two config files, A and B.
- Config files A and B both set the same ethernet interfaces in
  different ways. (different auth methods...)
- Config A file name is : 01-config.yaml
- Config B file name is : 99-config.yaml

**Question:**

1. Which config file will be applied?
2. Would config B work as a fallback if config A didn't work? Or the other way around? Or neither?
3. I want to set a fallback config file in case the existing one(A) fails. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A and B are not "separate" configs -- they are the building blocks of a single config.

They are **cumulative**. Example:

```
01-File:           02-File:
XYZ                XYZ
  Foo: True          Bar: [1,2,3]

Final config:
XYZ
  Foo: True
  Bar: [1,2,3]
```

The order of the files (01-99) is important when you have conflicting settings. Earlier settings are **overwritten** by later. This offers you the opportunity to override settings by placing a new file instead of editing the current files (much better for automated changes). Example:

```
01-File:           02-File:             03-File:
XYZ                XYZ                  XYZ
  Foo: True          Bar: [1,2,3]         Baz: Blue
  Baz: Green         Foo: False

Final config:
XYZ
  Foo: False
  Bar: [1,2,3]
  Baz: Blue
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining how it works. That helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you asked 3 questions ... instead of one. The simple respones look like

1. 01-config.yaml will be applied.
2. no
3. no

it is a bit unclear what you really want to do. If you provide more infos you will get more quallified answers. Is this question targeting WLAN and multiple SSIDs?